# Extract string and integer

Tags: regex, scala, regex-lookarounds

I want to extract the artist, song and integer from:

```
'WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND', 'DO YOUR THING', 0
```

I've been using this regex:

```
"""(?<=')(.+?)(?=')|(\d)""".r
```

How to convert this into a tuple? Output looks like

`(WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND, DO YOUR THING, 0)`

And how do I add a map function to do this tuple conversion to every such line

```
'Artist', 'Song', int(0 or 1) [Line format]
```

in a file?

I'm completely new to Scala so I don't really have any clues.

Comment: I can show you how to parse your input to tuple. However what is difference between your input and output formats? From what I can see for now there is no difference. In particular for your specific input: "'WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND', 'DO YOUR THING', 0" : what do you expect to be written into output file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have a pattern of `'artist', 'song', plays`, what sounds to works is a pattern `(')(artist)(',)(song)(',)(plays)`. So the regex would look like

```
scala> val extractionPattern = """(')(.*)(',\s+')(.*)(',\s+)(\d+)""".r
extractionPattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = (')(.*)(',\s+')(.*)(',\s+)(\d+)
```

given your input, it will give you 6 matches where you only care about 2nd, 4th and 6th one.

```
scala> extractionPattern.findAllIn("""'WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND', 'DO YOUR THING', 100""")
                        .matchData.map(_.subgroups).toList
res70: List[List[String]] = List(List(', WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND, ', ', DO YOUR THING, "', ", 100))
```

So just process the ones you care about,

```
scala> extractionPattern.findAllIn("""'WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND', 'DO YOUR THING', 100""")
                        .matchData.map(_.subgroups)
                        .flatMap(matches => Seq(matches(1), matches(3), matches(5))).toList
res71: List[String] = List(WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND, DO YOUR THING, 100)
```

See working regex online as well - https://regex101.com/r/vcBJcI/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! I found out that I was only having troubles when I was testing the regex with individual records. I'd forgotten to add the actual problem I faced in the question after I managed to get the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are processing CSV file ? If that's the case, I would consider using : https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv or some existing library.

If you just want to have fun, I'll join and without checking for other cases than what you provide the following regex code seems to work ( ?: is non capturing group)

```
val input = """'WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND', 'DO YOUR THING', 0"""
val regex = """(?:')(.+?)(?:')|\d""".r

regex.findAllIn(input).matchData.toList
```

produces :

```
List('WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND', 'DO YOUR THING', 0)
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/2fEtCsv/0

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you need to convert your input data to tuple and back to apparently the same output format (see my comment).
Anyway here is what you probably want:

```
  def matchData(s: String) = {
    val pattern = """('[\w\s]+'),\s*('[\w\s]+'),\s*(\d)""".r

    s match {
      case pattern(artist, song, n) => Some(artist, song, n)
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  List("""'WATTS 103RD STREET RHYTHM BAND', 'DO YOUR THING', 0""") map matchData map { mayBeTuple =>
    mayBeTuple match {
      case Some((artist, song, n)) => println(artist, song, n)
      case _ => // ignore
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I found out that I was only having troubles when I was testing the regex with individual records. I'd forgotten to add the actual problem I faced in the question after I managed to get the correct output.